# A closed question that has recieved multiple edits, opened again, then reverted to its original state, why can't I vote to close it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, vote-to-close, closing-questions

There seems to be an issue with [editing questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7403/the-difference-between-helpful-editing-and-vandalism), not yet (as of the date of this question) settled.

There is another, perhaps buggy issue with question edits, the initial form of [the question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/149536/how-to-play-music-during-post-apocalypse) was closed as too broad - I voted to put on-hold as such, I stand by this. Several edits were made, ultimately reverting to the original form that got put on hold as too-broad.

The question is now open, it is too broad as per JBH's 3rd answer posted [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types?noredirect=1&lq=1).

When I try to vote to close it as too broad, I receive a "you have already voted to close this question" pop-up, I view this as inappropriate and not-helpful.

**Call me patsy, but does this seem like we need to change the system in a way that facilitates free expression, not arbitrary historic limits being imposed?**

Comment: We have just under 30,000 users here on Worldbuilding. While most are not active, many thousands are. And this question has had 425 views (not all by users). The question's already been closed and reopened.  If 5 different users can't agree that it needs to be closed again, then we just need to accept that the community has spoken and let it be. No matter what you think of the question, there are truly countless others that are open but far more broad or unclear or opinion-based or anything else you might close for. (more)

Comment: I hear you on wanting to learn more about how VTC works; my concern is that, even after being told how it works, you still want to flag the question for closure.  Please don't.  It's done.  People have had the opportunity to close it (and to keep it closed) and right now it's open and will probably stay that way.

Comment: I flagged because I thought i was appropriate to do so, I've not heard a convincing argument to dissuade me of this opinion @Cyn , I guess you're right though, it'll probably stay open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each user is allowed only one close and one reopen vote on any one question.

[You participated](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/149536/revisions) in the original closure of the question at revision 3, and the reopening at revision 6.

Thus, you have used up your close and reopen votes on that particular question.

This is by design, and done at least in part to prevent close/reopen wars involving just a few users. Each close/reopen sequence needs either a diamond moderator, or a *different* set of five users with sufficient reputation to cast close and reopen votes.

See the [*cast close and reopen votes* privilege description in the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each individual user may cast at most one close and one reopen vote per question.

Comment: Would it therefore be appropriate to "flag it for closure" as the help center states in your link? I would think so.

Comment: @DonQualm I don't think you can do that once you have enough reputation to vote to close. However, I don't have a ready case to test it on. You could try; it might or might not actually work. I'm leaning toward that it won't work, but about the worst outcome is that you get an error message back saying something along the lines of that you've already used up your votes on the question.

Comment: Flag to close becomes a straight close vote once you have the rep for it.

Comment: @Separatrix I know it does when you are able to participate in closure. I'm not sure about the case where you have the rep, but can't participate in closure for other reasons. It makes sense that it would be the same thing, but in fairness, "makes sense" and "works that way" aren't always the same thing.

Comment: @DonQualm could flag for moderation intervention.  I do not think this is a good idea in this case, but it is technically available.